# Wrapping an object with a delegate

Tags: javascript

A bad title and this might not be the best way to do what I'm trying to do (still learning javascript) but I'm trying to wrap a object using a delegate. The object in this case is an XMLHttpRequest.

```
var wrapper = function() {
    this._delegate = /* get the delegate */
    this._delegate.onreadystatechange = function() {
        wrapper.readyState = this.readyState;

        /* stuff that synchronizes wrapper goes here */

        if(wrapper.onreadystatechange) {
            wrapper.onreadystatechange();
        }
    };
    return this;
}
```

The above is a simplification but when problem is that when I add an onreadystatefunction to the wrapper object like:

```
wrapper.onreadystatechange = function() {alert("hi)};
```

and the wrapper._delegate.onreadystatechange function is called, wrapper.onreadystatechange is always undefined and the alert popup never comes up. I think I'm getting my scope stuff wrong but I'm not exactly sure how to fix this. Would appreciate other suggestions but I would also like to know how to fix what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

EDIT

Yup it was an incomplete example. sorry about that. I realized after trying to rewrite it into a complete example what my cause my issue. It seems if I don't have the outer "WRAP_FUNCTION" then it will work fine. I had written something like

```
WRAP_FUNCTION = (function() {
    var originalXMLHttpRequest = window.XMLHttpRequest;
    var wrapper = function() {
        if(wrapper.wrapped) {
            this._delegate = new originalXMLHttpRequest;
        } else {
            this._delegate = new window.XMLHttpRequest
        }

        this._delegate.onreadystatechange = function() {
            wrapper.readyState = this.readyState;

            /* stuff that synchronizes wrapper goes here */

            if(wrapper.onreadystatechange) {
                wrapper.onreadystatechange();
            }
        };
        return this;
    };

    wrapper.prototype.open = function(method, url, async) {
        this._delegate.open(method, url, async);
    }

    wrapper.prototype.send = function() {
        this._delegate.send();
    }

    wrapper.wrapped = true;
    return wrapper;
}

window.XMLHttpRequest = WRAP_FUNCTION;
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="xmlhttp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var test = new XMLHttpRequest();
        test.open("GET", "xmlhttp.js", true);
        test.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (test.readyState==4 && test.status==200)
            {
                alert("yay");
            }
        };
        test.send();
    })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I made the thing all WRAP_FUNCTION because I was trying to implement a namespace

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this.

```
var wrapper = function() {
    // in this time var wrapper not yet defined completly
    // if you want use wrapper on the finction
    // need to use this instead of wrapper
    var self= this;

    this._delegate = /* get the delegate */
    this._delegate.onreadystatechange = function() {

        //this means _delegate  is in this time
        //if you want to use this(wrapper)       
        //set the value out of function
        //like var self= this  

        //wrapper.readyState = this.readyState;
        self.readyState = this.readyState;

        /* stuff that synchronizes wrapper goes here */

        //if(wrapper.onreadystatechange) {
        //    wrapper.onreadystatechange();
        //}
        if(self.onreadystatechange) {
            self.onreadystatechange();
        }
    };
    return this;
}
```

Comment: I think this sort of works but the alert doesn't come up. i posted this comment prematurely. gonna try some stuff out first

Comment: jckim0414, you lost me with the very first code comment 'in this time var wrapper not yet defined completly\n if you want use wrapper on the finction\nneed to use this instead of wrapper' ... I'm having trouble making any sense of that; it looks like words jumbled together!?  Similarly for the next comment which begins "this means _delegate  is in this time".

Comment: @jfriend00 - right, that's what I meant to say in my first comment, I think he added that material in response to your first comment, which makes your first comment look more absurd now than it probably did when you first wrote it.   Anyway, you've heard me; I'll delete all my comments here except for the one directed to jcklm0414 (which was a good idea, thanks for that); you might want to do the same.  Cheers.